# MySQL sorting distinct/unique values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-science

Decided to break my query in to bits, to help communicate what I am trying to achieve.

I have some information about a Customer and the Coupon Code they've used, in this format

| Customer | Coupon Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FreeDel |
| 1 | FreeDel |
| 1 | FreeDel |
| 1 | 1562733 |
| 1 | 8842939 |
| 1 | 847hr64 |
| 1 | 83jd63j |
| 1 | FreeDel |
| 1 | 8eh33jr |
| 1 | AA-2637 |
| 1 | AA-9837 |
| 1 | Save200 |
| 1 | Save200 |

I want to sort it so that: If a known coupon-code prefix is available, then using syntax like this:

CASE WHEN Coupon Code LIKE 'AA-%' THEN 'AA-'
CASE WHEN Coupon Code IS UNIQUE THEN 'UNIQUE'
CASE WHEN Coupon Code IS NOT UNIQUE THEN 'NON-UNIQUE'

And so to output

| Count | Customer | Coupon Code Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 1 | Non-Unique |
| 2 | 1 | AA- |
| 5 | 1 | Unique |

In this ideal, the known prefixes are added first as cases, and then unknown, unrepeated Coupon Codes are labelled Unique and then repeated Coupon Codes are labelled Non-Unique.

Any help would be super appreciated! :)

Table edits

Answer (score 1):

You could count them separately:

```
select sum(cnt), customer, 'Non-Unique'
from (
  select customer, coupon_code, count(*) as cnt
  from ccodes
  where coupon_code not like 'AA-%'
  group by customer, coupon_code
  having cnt>1
) as q
group by customer
union
select count(*), customer, 'AA-'
from ccodes
where coupon_code like 'AA-%'
group by customer
union
select sum(cnt), customer, 'Unique'
from (
  select customer, coupon_code, count(*) as cnt
  from ccodes
  where coupon_code not like 'AA-%'
  group by customer, coupon_code
  having cnt=1
) as q
group by customer
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vp5LDm3cBwy152h5rN13pN/1)

Comment: Thanks for this and especially `db-fiddle` as I was able to play and see exactly what you were thinking as you wrote this.  It's a shame the OP did not mark this as the answer nor up-vote it.  Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use aggregation and conditional logic:

```
(case when sum( code like 'AA-%' ) > 0 then 'AA-'
      when min(code) = max(code) then 'UNIQUE'
      else 'NON-UNIQUE'
 end)
```

You can incorporate this into an aggregation query as:

```
select grp, count(*)
from (select c.customer,
             (case when sum( code like 'AA-%' ) > 0 then 'AA-'
                   when min(code) = max(code) then 'UNIQUE'
                   else 'NON-UNIQUE'
              end) as grp,
             count(*)
      from c
      group by customer
     ) x
group by grp;
```

Comment: I don't follow - how will that count the number of unique and non-unique instances?

Comment: @UsmaanBhatti . . . You would incorporate the logic into an aggregation query.  I edited the answer.